# TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined on Vue-i18n

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, internationalization, vue-component, vue-i18n

I am using Vue-i18n currently for the project.

From what I learned, all the words that are to be translated need to use `$t`.

Is there any way to change `$t` to something else instead? Maybe some method to overwrite?

For example, instead of: `{{ $t('name') }}`

Change it to: `{{ $ba('name') }}`

---

I managed to do it using @Alex method, but over [i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/blob/f2b8a1024d8a0772ada501f5eac21d0471b0a35d/dist/vue-i18n.esm.js).

But if I changed return parameters as well (from `$t` to `$ba`), there will be an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`.

Is there any way to solve this?

```
function extend (Vue) {
Vue.prototype.$ba = function (key) {
    var values = [], len = arguments.length - 1;
    while ( len-- > 0 ) values[ len ] = arguments[ len + 1 ];

    var i18n = this.$i18n;
    return i18n._ba.apply(i18n, [ key, i18n.locale, i18n._getMessages(), this ].concat( values ))
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t is only some variable that was attached to `Vue.prototype`. You can see it being assigned in source code of [i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/blob/f2b8a1024d8a0772ada501f5eac21d0471b0a35d/src/extend.js). So after you do `Vue.install(i18n)`, you can just override all these prototypes and create whatever names you want.

Comment: Hi @Alex, thank you for your reply. I am assigning it at `dist` over i18n.. However if I change the return parameters together with the variable of `Vue.prototype`, it will appears `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.` Is there any way to solve this problem? I have updated the code on above question. Thank you.

Comment: What is inside of $i18n?

Comment: I just followed the original source code over [i18n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/blob/f2b8a1024d8a0772ada501f5eac21d0471b0a35d/dist/vue-i18n.esm.js), just changing the `Vue.prototype.$ba` and `return i18n._ba.apply`. Thank you.